# Learning PHP Framework for ecommerce site

Tags: php, ecommerce, books

Are there any books that can teach a good/useful PHP framework to build an ecommerce site? Please recommend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*PHP 5 e-commerce Development*](http://www.packtpub.com/php-5-e-commerce-development/book) starts by creating a simple MVC-style framework, then continues to teach you how to build an e-commerce system with PHP.

[*Effortless E-Commerce with PHP and MySQL*](http://www.peachpit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=9780321656223) teaches custom e-commerce development with PHP.

[*WordPress 2.9 E-Commerce*](http://www.packtpub.com/wordpress-2-9-e-commerce/book) shows how to use PHP, WordPress, and the WP-Commerce plugin to build an e-commerce site.

[*Joomla! E-Commerce with VirtueMart*](http://www.packtpub.com/joomla-e-commerce-with-virtuemart-1-1-x/book) builds an e-commerce site using Joomla.

[*Drupal E-commerce with Ubercart 2.x*](https://www.packtpub.com/drupal-e-commerce-with-ubercart-2-x/book) demonstrates e-commerce site builds using Drupal.

[*Building PHP Applications with Symfony™, CakePHP, and Zend® Framework*](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0470887346.html) gives an overview of working with three popular PHP frameworks, with concepts that could be applied to developing a shop.

Comment: Since there are so many frameworks out there, which would you use to create a simple ecommerce site (complete with checkouts, users, etc)? Or would you just create it from scratch?

Comment: I've built online shops with WordPress, CodeIgniter, and custom PHP, and find doing it from scratch easiest. You code only what you need, have a better understanding of what every line does, and need not worry about the initial learning curve or inevitable code refactoring when YourFramework 3.0 comes out.

Comment: Thanks, is there a place that I can learn to do this with custom PHP?

Answer (score 0):

The Zend framework can help you with your project.  A good book is "Zend Framework in Action".  Get it [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1933988320).

Comment: That's not a book. It's software.

Comment: I also don't think it's a Framework, but since I'm new to php I could be wrong...

Comment: Changed my answer to be more in line with the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason why you're looking for a framework to aid you with this task?

I'd say with the complexity of e-commerce applications (Yes, you can make a 'simple' one, but it's still going to be pretty complicated by the time you're done with frontend/backend, order management, payment gateways, etc etc) that you might want to consider possibly writing your own framework so you fully understand what your code is doing - this way you can also ensure what you're doing is 'secure' - which is pretty key when it comes to money changing hands.

Granted, Magento uses the Zend framework, but it's all heavily customized etc to be their own.